# Variable in php back as null in global

Tags: php, function, null, joomla1.5, global

I have try loads of ways and have done this before with no issue, but I can not get this one to work:

```
$item_img = "my_image_name.jpg";

function GetImage(){
    global $item_img;
    return $item_img;
}
```

It returns null. Why?

Comment: [Works for me](http://codepad.org/eEbpAP8M).

Comment: You probably have an exceedingly simple but easy-to-miss typo or something.  That code works perfectly for me.

Comment: This particular piece of code does *nothing*. How/when/where are you actually calling `GetImage`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$item_img = "my_image_name.jpg";

function GetImage(){
    global $item_img;
    return $item_img;
}

var_dump( GetImage() );

?>
```

It returns **string(17) "my_image_name.jpg"**  and not NULL. You are doing something wrong...

Try this in Joomla module :

```
<?php

$item_img = "my_image_name.jpg";

function GetImage($img){
    # do something with $img
    return $img;
}

var_dump( GetImage($item_img) );

?>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks... I have run this in a separte file and it is fine, but when I use in a joomla module it does not work.

Comment: strange... i have never worked with joomla, so i cannot help here. but you can try another approach, like one i posted up?

Comment: I think there is a legit reason fot this. Example for this behaviour could be, that your code is run from some function/method in Joomla core. Don't know Joomla, so cannot really say what is going on there.

Answer (score 0):

Does not return `null` for me. Which version of PHP do you use?

```
<?php
$item_img = "my_image_name.jpg";

function GetImage(){
    global $item_img;
    return $item_img;
}

var_dump(GetImage());
// string 'my_image_name.jpg' (length=17)
```